# Why is my code treating " " (a space) as a consonant?

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement

How can I make this code go over spaces without treating them as consonants? The example below, "text message", should return "tx msg", the code only prints consonants that don't have another consonant before them (and words that are only composed of vowels), but it returns "txmsg" instead. It's treating the space as a consonant so it deletes the space itslef and the m.

```
def getMessage(original):
    newMessage = ''
    for i in range(len(original)):
        if isConsonant(original[i]) and isVowel(original[i - 1]):
            newMessage += original[i]
    return newMessage
def isVowel(letter):
    vowel = "a" "e" "i" "o" "u" "y" "A" "E" "I" "O" "U" " "
    if letter in vowel:
        return True
    return False
def isConsonant(letter):
    vowel = "a" "e" "i" "o" "u" "y" "A" "E" "I" "O" "U"
    if letter not in vowel:
        return True
    return False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(getMessage("text message"))
```

Comment: because `" "` is not in `"aeiou"`, and thusly `letter not in vowel` is clearly true ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley when i add a " " to the isVowel list, it prints txmsg, wihtout a space in between. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `original[i]` only if its a consonant (and before has a vowel) which `space` its not. Add a special case for it.

```py
        if (isConsonant(original[i]) and isVowel(original[i - 1])) or original[i]==' ':
```

Comment: Added, what would be inside the if statement though?

Comment: Because its a special case to be considered that does not follows the consonant/vowel condition that you where only considering before